# Not able to build XERCESS 3.2.3 on MAC for arm64 configuration

Tags: xml-parsing, fast-xml-parser, apache-xml-graphics

I am trying to build xerces 3.2.3 for ARM64 configuration on MAC 10.15 using XCODE 12.2 but it fails with error that **
This header is for x86 only
This is coming from Cupid.h

can Xerces-c 3.2,3 build on  MAC for ARM64 configuration?

Comment: yes, I also have the same. are you able to resolve this yet?

Answer (score 0):

use aarch64

```
export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.15
./configure CFLAGS="-arch arm64" CXXFLAGS="-arch arm64"   --host aarch64
```